# fish executing file with relative path

Tags: shell, wsl-2, fish

I'm having an issue where I can't run `fish x.fish` or `fish ./x.fish`, but I can run `fish (pwd)/x.fish`, AKA using an absolute path to my file instead of a relative one or with `.`. I haven't had this issue in previous installations, but my setup is a bit different this time so I'd appreciate any advice.

Version:
`fish --version` = `fish, version 3.3.1`.

Setup: installed `fish` as shell in Windows 11 WSL, and set it as default shell.

My script named `main.fish`:

```
echo "in main.fish script"
```

running in the `main.fish`'s parent directory:

`fish main.fish` = `main.fish: No such file or directory`

`fish /main.fish` = `./main.fish: No such file or directory`

`fish (pwd)/main.fish` = `in main.fish script`

What is stopping me from running a fish file with a relative path? Maybe unrelated, setting the file to executable and running `./main.fish` and adding `#! /usr/bin/fish` results in `./main.fish: No such file or directory`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm stumped. Reiterating, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I ran `strace fish.main`, and it's large but ends with

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "main.fish", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x4), ...}) = 0
write(3, "main.fish: No such file or direc"..., 37main.fish: No such file or directory
) = 37
close(3)                                = 0
getpid()                                = 11251
getpgrp()                               = 11248
ioctl(0, TIOCGPGRP, [11248])            = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

Comment: I suggest using `strace` to understand which syscall is failing and the arguments passed to it.

Comment: I've added the bottom of the result of `strace fish main.fish` in an edit, although I don't know what to think of it.

Comment: I've found this quote "If pathname is relative and `dirfd` is the special value `AT_FDCWD`, then pathname is interpreted relative to the current working directory of the calling process (like open(2))." which makes me think it is trying to open the correct file. At here https://linux.die.net/man/2/openat

Comment: Running `sudo fish main.fish` works, so I think it's a permissions issue. Thanks for pointing me toward `strace`.

Comment: There isn't anything obvious in the information you've provided other than the presence of "sandbox" in the PWD. Which suggests you installed fish in an unusual fashion meant to sandbox its behavior. So, yeah, a permission issue related to how you created that sandbox and launched the fish process in that sandbox.

Comment: Yeah, `sandbox` is just the name of folders I put example/temporary code. It's a regular directory. I checked the file permissions and didn't see anything weird, so I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/9040.

Fish always reads its configuration, even non-interactively.

That means if you have a `cd ~` in config.fish, then running

```
fish ./x.fish
```

will start fish, which will cd to the home directory, and then attempt to run "x.fish" *in the home directory*.

The solution is to guard that `cd ~` with `status is-interactive`:

```
if status is-interactive
    cd ~
end
```

(or remove it entirely)